# How can I create a local USDT testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, docker, usdt, tether

I want to create a local testnet on which I can move USDT (test coins) between wallets.

I managed to create a ETH testnet inside Docker. In the `docker-compose.yml` below, the lines between `# ETH testnet setup (start)` and `# ETH testnet setup (end)` are responsible for that.

```
version: '3'

services:
#
# BTC testnet setup (start)
#
  node:
    image: ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest:latest
  electrumx:
    image: lukechilds/electrumx:latest
    links:
      - node
    ports:
      - "51001:50001"
      - "51002:50002"
    environment:
      - NET=regtest
      - COIN=BitcoinSegwit
      - DAEMON_URL=http://test:test@node:19001
  explorer:
    image: ulamlabs/btc-rpc-explorer:latest
    links:
      - node
      - electrumx
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    environment:
      - BTCEXP_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - BTCEXP_BITCOIND_URI=http://test:test@node:19001
      - BTCEXP_ELECTRUMX_SERVERS=tls://electrumx:50002
      - BTCEXP_ADDRESS_API=electrumx
#
# BTC testnet setup (end)
#


#
# ETH testnet setup (start)
#
  geth:
    image: ulamlabs/geth-poa-testnet:latest
    environment:
      - ETH_PASSWORD=QfdxTYxkwASj
      - ETH_PRIVATE_KEY=0d0b4c455973c883bb0fa584f0078178aa90c571a8f1d40f28d2339f4e757dde
      - ETH_ADDRESS=0c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e654993339
    ports:
      - 8178:8178
      - 8546:8546
    volumes:
      - ./genesis.json:/app/genesis.json

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=500'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

  blockscout:
    image: ulamlabs/blockscout:latest
    links:
      - geth
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:@postgres:5432/postgres?ssl=false
      - ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_VARIANT=geth
      - ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_HTTP_URL=http://geth:8178
      - ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_WS_URL=ws://geth:8546
      - MIX_ENV=prod
      - BLOCKSCOUT_HOST=localhost
      - COIN=eth
      - NETWORK=POA
      - SUBNETWORK=Local Testnet

#
# ETH testnet setup (end)
#
```

The file `./genesis.json:/app/genesis.json` contains the following:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 5555,
        "clique": {
            "period": 60,
            "epoch": 30000
        },
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "constantinopleBlock": 0,
        "petersburgBlock": 0,
        "istanbulBlock": 0,
        "muirGlacierBlock": 0
    },
    "extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e6549933390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
        "411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28": {
            "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    },
    "nonce": "0x0",
    "timestamp": "0x5eaa7b09",
    "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
    "difficulty": "0x1",
    "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "number": "0x0",
    "gasUsed": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

As far as I understand,

- no USDT test coins are being mined in this testnet and
- in order to have USDT test coins I need to add ERC20 support to the ETH (geth) testnet.

**How do I need to modify the above `docker-compose.yml` and/or `genesis.json` files in order to add ERC20/USDT support to my ETH testnet?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer as best as I can, although the question is not 100% clear to me.

### Eth transfer

Transfer of Ether between accounts is handled natively by the blockchain. You do not need to deploy any smart contract to do so.

### ERC-20 transfer

USDT and other ERC-20 tokens do not exist natively on the blockchain. Each ERC-20 token is a smart contract that was deployed by someone. For instance, [this](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) is the USDT contract address. You can also read the USDT contract code [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code).

### USDT on testnet

To answer your question, you can test USDT on a testnet by deploying an exact copy of the USDT contract (linked above) on that testnet, then calling some functions like `transfer()` on the smart contract.

Note that you do not need to create your own testnet. You could use a public testnet like Ropsten, Kovan, Rinkeby, etc. You could also do a local fork of Ethereum mainnet using a tool like ganache-cli. With the latter, the USDT contract is already deployed and you can test it on your local fork of Ethereum mainnet. [Ganache-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache-cli) also allows you to create a local testnet very easily.

Comment: I have a list of 10 accounts in Ganache. Can you explain how I transfer USDT to one of them?

Comment: This is the USDT contract source code even though the word usdt is not mentioned at all?

Comment: Yes. Etherscan shows that this is the USDT token address

Comment: To elaborate  the contract name is tether which is USDT, also the USDT name and symbol were passed in constructor therefore you don't see it in the contract itself `function TetherToken(uint _initialSupply, string _name, string _symbol`